# What are the most relevant resources that define the face detection problem formally?

Tags: computer-vision, reference-request, face-detection

I am new to AI, and I am a bit lost about finding the relevant materials that define the face detection problem formally/mathematically.

Can anyone help me formally define face detection, or at least point me towards papers that define it formally?